# Regular Expression for Organisation name

Tags: javascript, regex

How to write a regular expression for validating a organisation name which allows Alphanumeric as the starting characters and only special characters like `.`, `-`, `#` and `&`.

I tried but it's not working

```
/^[a-z]|\d?[a-zA-Z0-9]?[a-zA-Z0-9\s&@.]+$
```

**Some Valid Names**

Hercules.Cycle
Herbal & Product
Welcome @ 123

**Invalid Names**

&Hercules
Colgate!()
.Youtube
@Incule

Comment: Please add some samples for which is failing.

Comment: And how did you try it? *What* is not working?  Please add valid and invalid inputs.

Comment: Please provide some examples of valid and invalid names

Comment: Why does an *organization name* need validating in the first place? What about umlauts and other special characters that might be present in a company name?

Comment: Organisation names can't include '!' characters? [Since when](http://info.yahoo.com/center/us/yahoo/)?

Comment: I have seen organization names with parentheses, Japanese characters, exclamation marks and even question marks.

Comment: vivek, is it homework? If so, you should tag accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

Is that what you want?

`^[A-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9]|[- @\.#&!])*$`

Comment: Its allowing all the special characters

Answer (score 3):

You guys can use this below validation ,

As per our requirement from client, "Company Name" can have only 'single space' in between words along with few permitted special characters in it.

/^[a-zA-Z0-9-@.{}#&!()]+(\s[a-zA-Z0-9-@{}.#&!()]+)+(\s[a-zA-Z-@.#&!()]+)?$/

**Output:-**
**Correct/Positive Response.**
These below mentioned outputs are allowed..

- @arshaa Technologies (m91) HYD
- @9Arshaa Technologies (HYD) IND
- #AT&T {IND} HYD
- #Apple.India {HYD} (INDIA)

**Negative/Incorrect response.**
These below mentioned few outputs will not be allowed, according to above mentioned RegEx. As they contain multiple spaces or Special Characters not in RegEx.

- @arshaa   _Technologies (m91) HYD
- @9Arshaa --Technologies    (HYD) IND
- #AT&T {IND}                HYD.
- #Apple.     -^India {HYD} $(INDIA)

Note: Please feel free to update your answers in comments section for further modification of this RegEx.

Answer (score 1):

I've made and tested the above regular expression and it solves all what you mentioned:

```
/^[.@&]?[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+[ !.@&()]?[ a-zA-Z0-9!()]+/
```

Below all checks off.

**Some Valid Names**

- Hercules.Cycle
- Herbal & Product
- Welcome @ 123

**Invalid Names**

- &Hercules
- Colgate!()
- .Youtube
- @Incule

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:
`^\w[\w.\-#&\s]*$`
or
`^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\.\-#&\s]*$`

Comment: it allows all the special characters

Comment: @vivek, are you sure? It allows only `.`, `-`, `#`, `&`

Answer (score 0):

^[A-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9.-_,]|[- @.#&!])*$

This would allow certain special characters after the first word
**Sample Names**: 
 1. Hoyt, Gilman & Esp
 2. Y 105 Kgfy